# Bower install Libraries Issues

Tags: javascript, git, command-line, terminal, bower

I am using bower to install dependencies and various libraries in my project. But I am getting a fatal error. The URL's **git://** portion seems to be replaced by **insteadof**

I am using **Mac OS X** and **Terminal** for commands.

Is there any solution for this?

```
pdc1-4s6zyr1:~ administrator$ bower install **git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git**
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: '.insteadofgithub.com/jquery/jquery.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Comment: Could you post your bower.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your terminal and write this:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

This will force git replace the protocol.

Also if you are including github repos in your **bower.json** you can try replacing 'git://' by 'https://' of git URL's in the file.

Comment: It didnt work. It is still showing the same error. Do you know how to completely remove git configurations?

Comment: @AnkitTanna you can look for the config file: ~/.gitconfig and remove all settings. Could something be wrong with your bower file?

Comment: Hi, the problem was one of the url was having blank value.  just added https [url "https://"]

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem is:

Find the .gitconfig file

```
 [user]
        name = 1wQasdTeedFrsweXcs234saS56Scxs5423
        email = ankittanna@hotmail.com
    [credential]
        helper = osxkeychain
    [url ""]
        insteadOf = git://
    [url "https://"]
    [url "https://"]
        insteadOf = git://
```

there would be a blank url="" replace it with url="https://"

```
[user]
    name = 1wQasdTeedFrsweXcs234saS56Scxs5423
    email = ankittanna@hotmail.com
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[url "https://"]
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

This will work :)

Happy Bower-ing